# No se muestran los cambios en mi web hasta presionar F5

Tags: php, mysql, web

Estoy diseñando mi página web. La tengo programada con php y mysql.

Mi problema es que al publicarla en el host las consultas no muestran los cambios hasta que recargo la página.

Esto parece ser problema del host que contrate porque en mi localhost actualiza al momento sin necesidad de presionar <kbd>F5</kbd>.

estube revisando el `.htaccess` pero está en blanco, no tiene alguna instrucción para se guarde en caché o algo similar.

Dato extra: el host que me presenta el problema es https://pagina.mx

Comment: ¿Podrías facilitarnos un enlace a alguna página a la que le pase eso? Es probable que tu hosting use un acelerador web u otra aplicación de nivel 7 que esté agregando cabeceras de caché que debas evadir o impedir (ver la respuesta del compañero para una forma de solucionarlo). Pero necesitamos más datos para saber en qué caso estás y cómo darle solución exacta a tu problema.

Answer (score 2):

En el php donde generas el resultado de la consulta puedes forzar a que no actuen las cachés con los siguientes comandos de php

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
```

Al ser comandos header deberían ejecutarse antes de que envíes con echos, prints, ... nada al navegador.